# How to put the different message in cc?

Tags: php

I just want some help in php mail function .I done the code of mail function every thing is wrking fine but now i want to add cc to two diff users .
I added the cc functionality also but now i want to send the diff message in CC.
Means that To and CC having different messages how to do that one.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Email doesn't work like that.

A CCed message is identical to the original message. It is, in fact, the same message. The mail server just delivers it to multiple places.

If you want to send different messages, send different emails.

Comment: Also historically `CC` originates from the word `carbon copy` back from the old paper only days, so it is (and should indeed be) just a copy.

Comment: @Sujitha be sure to mark as an answer if it solved your problem to prevent future responses that do not ;)